# Ionic cannot navigate to a specific tab upon notification clicked?

Tags: ionic-framework, notifications, ionic3

I am using Ionic and FCM(firebase) plugin to send push notification. I can receive notifications, when I tap the notification it triggers the alert successfully but it is not navigating to the specified tab. Just to make sure this line:

```
this.tab.select(2);
```

works I have tested navigating with that code with a button and it works

```
      FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){
    if(data.wasTapped){
      //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.

     alert('data was tapped');
        this.tab.select(2);
          //this.navCtrl.push(ViewurgentnewsPage); also tried this

    }else{
      //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.

        alert('this was received on foreground');


    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **arrow functions**

```
  FCMPlugin.onNotification((data) => {
    if(data.wasTapped){
      //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
      alert('data was tapped');
      this.tab.select(2);
    } else {
      //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
      alert('this was received on foreground');
    }
  });
```

By using arrow function, the `this` keyword still references the component code, where the `this.tab` property exists.